# Working with routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

On the site I have created I can see the URL that I will be taken to, if I hover the mouse a link or tab. This will appear in the bottom left corner, and dissappear again when I remove the mouse. But if the user clicks on a tab or link, and is taken to a new page, he can't see in the URL what page he is on. I'm not sure if routing is what I am looking for here? Basically what I want to achieve, is that the user can see in the URL where he is.

Right now it just says `localhost:3918#`, where I want something like `localhost:3918/Software/about`. Why I ended up reading about Routing, is because when I search something like asp.net URLs, or show path etc, the majority of the results is Asp.net Routing. But Routing just describes how to obtain routes/path, and it's already default in asp.net mvc, according to this:

```
Adding Routes to an MVC Application
```

"*If you adopt the MVC convention of implementing controllers by creating classes that derive from the ControllerBase class and giving them names that end with "Controller", you do not need to manually add routes in an MVC application. The preconfigured routes will invoke the action methods that you implement in the controller classes.*"

Comment: If its a jquery based tab plugin or something similar, then the hashes are normal for in page navigation. Here is an [example](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000049.htm) of in page navigating. And here is an [example](http://os.alfajango.com/easytabs/) of a tab system I refer to.

Comment: I think you need to give us an example code of what you're trying to do. Without context we're just throwing things at the wall waiting for you to tell us if it stuck or if we're even close.

Comment: If your seeing `localhost:3918` when your expect `localhost:3918/Software/about` its because your default route is `controller = "Software", action="about"` (and in response to your comment in Chris' answer, you can send this url to a friend)

Answer (score 0):

What you're talking about is not a feature of the website, but rather the browser. The browser is showing the tooltip in the lower corner to let the user know where the link will take them. You can't control this.

In general, though, I don't see what problem you're trying to solve here. The user can very much see where they are currently via the address bar in their browser. There's no need to display it on the actual page as well.

Comment: I think it is nice to know where I currently am when surfing on some sites. For example right now, I can see in the url that I am on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29288601/working-with-routing

Then I can send this url to a friend, if I know that this topic is helpful to him. I can't do this on my site, since it doesn't show what page he is on. It's fine that it shows this in the left bottom corner, but he can't c&p it and send it to someone

Comment: _"The user can very much see where they are currently via the address bar in their browser"_. This is the problem, they CAN'T see the address in the address bar. It doesn't show